# See Windows' files from Ubuntu's default folder?

Tags: directory

I have dual boot installation. Can I set, for example, my Downloads folder in Ubuntu partition to show contents from certain folder in my Windows' partition without actually copying the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create a link to that specific Windows directory in your Ubuntu home folder. For example, I have my Windows partition mounted on */media/davide* with name its UUID. So for me, Windows is accessible at the folder */media/davide/"WindowsPartitionUUID"*, where WindowsPartitionUUID is the UUID of the partition in which I have Windows file system.
With the command

> ln -s /media/davide/"WindowsPartitionUUID"/Users/davide/Downloads/ ~

I can create a symbolic link to my Downloads Windows folder in my Ubuntu home folder (~). Obviously, it depends on where you have mounted your Windows partition.
To see where it has been mounted, you can launch the command

> cat /etc/fstab

and get the second column of the line corresponding to your Windows mounting partition which describes the path to Windows.

If you don't have your */etc/fstab* manually configured, you can spot your Windows mounting point by launching

> lsblk

It shows all the drives mounted on the system with the corresponding mount point.

Answer (score 0):

You can link it with soft link, for example:

```
ln -sf /media/windows/user/documents ~/Downloads
```

It will link "document" folder to your "Download" folder. It means you can see and access your document folder inside Downloads, just "soft link", without copying files.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't make my ~/Downloads folder able to show the content of my Windows folder, but only put that Windows folder's link in the ~/Downloads folder. Not my desired result.